# I want to check if the user output is odd or even but it only accepts integer but when I run it will always show invalid even the use puts an integer

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a = (input("Enter a Whole Number: "))


if type(a)== int:
    if a % 2 == 0:
        print ("Even")
    elif b % 2 != 0:
        print ("odd")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

I want the output will put an invalid if the user will put a non integer. Answer if it is a odd or even if the user put an integer

Comment: You tagged this with a *very old and no longer supported* Python version. Are you _certain_ this is a Python 2.7 issue?

Comment: In fact, only if you run this code with Python 3 (the current major Python version) would you experience this issue. Your code would work fine in Python 2.7.